# Is hydroboration a pericyclic reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

According to Ahn.N.T "Frontier Orbitals" hydroboration isn't a pericyclic reaction because boron uses two AOs and not one. The same applies for cheletropic reactions, which aren't pericyclic either. But the IUPAC goldbook says different: http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04491.html - that cheletropic reactions are pericyclic. So is hydroboration, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [IUPAC Goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04491.html) definition, the only two requirements for a pericyclic reaction are:

1. Concerted mechanism
2. Cyclic transition state

Hydroboration reactions (and similar reactions) are pericylic reactions by these criteria, as are all cheletropic reactions.

The language about `fully conjugated transition states` can be used to explain some pericyclic reactions, but not all, and thus IUPAC uses the phrasing `may be viewed as...`. Hydride shifts, (and all sigmatropic rearrangements ene reactions) involve non-$\pi$ orbitals (even so, the transition states do tend to follow the Hückel rule).

Comment: What type of pericyclic reaction is hydroboration?

Comment: It's similar to an [ene-reaction](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02099.html), but I am not saying that it is an ene reaction. Does it need to fit easily into a subcategory?

Comment: I guess not... .